# In C, how to read the memory chunk preceding an address

Tags: c, pointers, memory

Given a struct object or a pointer to one, how can I read, say x bytes of memory, preceding the object? For example, if I know the object start at address 10, how can I read x bytes from address 10-x to address 9? Thank you.

Comment: cast to char*, then subtract "x", and you get a pointer to the bytes preceding. That's like an array as far as you're concerned.

Comment: you can get the address as the previous comment says but access to it may be undefined. what if this is being used by another object,for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading bytes from any address is easy: simply cast the pointer to a `char*`, subtract the desired number of bytes, and start reading, like this:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int x;
    int y;
} test[100];
...
void *ptr = &test[50];
...
char *start = (char*)prt;
start -= 10;
// You can read from the start pointer now
```

You need to make sure that the memory that you are trying to read is legal for your application to access. The memory needs to be part of a larger structure that you allocated statically or dynamically. Otherwise, it is undefined behavior, which may lead to a crash.

Comment: Put it another way, if I want to read 2 preceding bytes, can I do "int* start = (int*)prt; start -=1; int t=*start" ?

Comment: @cody No, that would read two preceding `int`s, not two preceding bytes. You need to cast to `char*` before subtracting 2, otherwise you are subtracting `2*sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

Like **Nitzan Shaked** said in the comment, cast the pointer to `(char *)` so that you can do pointer-arithmetic at the byte level. Then do the pointer arithmetic (subtract the number of bytes you need to subtract), then cast it back to a pointer of the type of thing you need to read it as.